# Import CSV with row delimiters into Excel using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

Need a help with a PowerShell script to import a CSV file with the column delimiters as `|` and the row delimiters as `&` (not carriage return) into Excel.

Here is the sample of CSV file:

```
row1col1|row1col2|row1col3|row1col4&row2col1|row2col2|row2col3|row2col4&row3col1|row3col2|row3col3|row3col4 etc.
```

I found this script, but in only works when row delimiter is CR (carriage return). What lines should I add to make it work with `&` symbol, not CR.

```
#Define locations and delimiter
$csv = "file.csv"   #Location of the source file
$xlsx = "file.xlsx" #Desired location of output

$delimiter = "|" #Specify the delimiter used in the file

# Create a new Excel workbook with one empty sheet
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

# Build the QueryTables.Add command and reformat the data
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $csv)

$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.Add($TxtConnector, $worksheet.Range("A1"))

$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.Item($Connector.Name)
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $delimiter
$query.TextFileParseType = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,1 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

# Execute & delete the import query
$query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()

# Save & close the Workbook as XLSX.
$Workbook.SaveAs($xlsx, 51)
$excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Replace & with new line (ensure first that there's no & in data).

Comment: I don't think there is a database connector for text files that doesn't expect table rows to be separated by newlines. The `Workbooks.Open()` and `Workbooks.OpenText()` methods also only allow for specifying *column* delimiters, not *row* delimiters. Replacing the row delimiter in your input file is probably your best option.

Answer (score 2):

Most of he time I use the module ImportExcel (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) to import or export data to/from Excel. It is much faster then the com interface. That makes my solution a 2-liner

```
(Get-Content .\sample.csv) -replace '&',"`r`n" |Set-Content .\sample.csv
Import-Csv .\sample.csv -Delimiter '|' | Export-Excel -Path .\export2.xlsx -WorksheetName SHEET1
```

Again: you need a module. It works even when Excel is not installed!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a text connector with everything on one line.  You'll have to add some code at the beginning of your script to get it to work.

```
$folder = 'c:\path\to\file'
$file = 'test.csv'
$delimiter = '|'
$lineseparator = '&'

$csvfile = Join-Path $folder $file

# step by step
$contents = Get-Content $csvfile -Raw
$replacedcontents = $contents -replace $lineseparator, "`r`n"
$replacedcontents | Out-File $csvfile -Force

# or use this oneliner
(Get-Content $csvfile -Raw) -replace $lineseparator, "`r`n" | Out-File $csvfile -Force
```

I've used `` `r`n `` (the Windows standard, char 13 & 10) but it will probably work with just `` `n `` as well.